# javascript regular expression match a string at some rules?

Tags: javascript, regex

My purpose is to find a function that checks if a string starts with a lower-case letter, ends with a lower-case letter, may contain only one or no hyphen `-`, and is less than or equal to 32 characters.

The following is my code:

```js
var ss = /^[a-z]+([A-Za-z0-9_]|(-?)|[a-z]+$){1,31}/;
str="ss-fjdkkldjkskjdskjdksjdkjdkjklskssdkdkffdkdfkdfk";
ss.test(str);
```

test string
result with true
aJDS-a a234bds aHJH878sjkJSK-ja

My function is currently returning `true` and doesn't match my requirement.
If the test string match reg requirement, the result should return true.
I don't know why.

Comment: The test string you posted starts with a lower-case letter, ends with a lower-case letter, and has a - in the middle.  Why would you expect that to return false?

Comment: why should it return false? it is matching your condition

Comment: because it doesn't match the requirement

Comment: The `-` requirement is not clear: can there be any number of them inside the string? Try [`^(?=[\w-]{1,31}$)[a-z](?:[\w-]*[a-z])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/btNpor/1).

Comment: How about using, `(ss.test(str) && str.length <= 32)` with a simpler regex `^[a-z]+-?\w+[a-z]$` [**jsFiddle Demo`**](https://jsfiddle.net/7hqr1qkq/3/)

Comment: add an example where it should return true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `[A-Za-z0-9_]` in JS regex is equal to `\w`. So, here are several solutions to your problem:

- The length of the whole string is checked either with code (`str.length > 0 && str.length <= 32`) or using a `(?=.{1,32}$)` positive lookahead after `^` start-of-string anchor in the regex suggestions below
- If you need to only match a string when it contains a single `-` somewhere inside, use an optional non-capturing group like this - `^[a-z]\w*(?:-\w*[a-z])?$` (=> [`^(?=.{1,31}$)[a-z]\w*(?:-\w*[a-z])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/xPfycz/1))
- If that hyphen is optional, add `?` quantifier after it: `^[a-z]\w*(?:-?\w*[a-z])?$` (=> [`^(?=.{1,31}$)[a-z]\w*(?:-?\w*[a-z])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/JgcD93/1))
- If you need to only match a string when it contains any number of `-` somewhere inside, use `^[a-z](?:[-\w]*[a-z])?$` (=> [`^(?=.{1,31}$)[a-z](?:[-\w]*[a-z])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/rKDl3N/1/)).